# VBO with textures, without deprecated functions

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, vbo

I am trying to write a basic Quad-renderer, using VBO, VAO, IBO and shaders.
I am trying to use mainly only one VBO, VAO, IBO and rebuffer the data when an element is added/removed.
Mostly everything worked fine, until I decided to implement textures, instead of color gradings.

It just doesn't draw anyhting, no matter what I try, because I want to avoid using deprecated functions like ClientStates and maybe use the textures inside the shaders.

Next to the problem, that nothing is being drawn, I have the problem that the Textures are saved inside the BRectangle class, and now I don't know, how to access them while using DrawElements.

And can I reuse my IBO, so I don't have to add the additional indices?

My current approach:

The Renderer, you can add a Rectangle atm and it will buffer the needed data.

```
    public class ShaderRenderer {

    public static final int POSITION_INDEX = 0; // index of vertex attribute "in_Position"
    public static final int TEXTURE_INDEX = 1; // index of vertex attribute "in_Texture"

    public static final int FLOAT_NUM_BYTES; // sizeof(float) in bytes
    public static final int INT_NUM_BYTES; // sizeof(int) in bytes
    public static final int VEC4_BYTES; // sizeof(vec4) in bytes

    static {
        FLOAT_NUM_BYTES = Float.SIZE / Byte.SIZE;
        INT_NUM_BYTES = Integer.SIZE / Byte.SIZE;
        VEC4_BYTES = 4 * FLOAT_NUM_BYTES;
    }

    private VAO vao = new VAO();
    private VBO vbo = new VBO();
    private IBO ibo = new IBO();

    private int elements = 0;

    public ShaderRenderer() {
        try {
            ShaderUtilities.compileShader("shaders/screen.vert", "shaders/screen.frag", POSITION_INDEX, TEXTURE_INDEX);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void add( BRectangle rect ) {

        // Bind the VAO
        // This OpenGL-object groups the "in_Position" and "in_Color"
        // vertex attributes.
        vao.bind();

        // Bind the VBO and add the FloatBuffer from the Rect
        vbo.bind();
        vbo.addBuffer(rect.vertexData);

        ibo.bind();
        ibo.addIndices(generateIndices());
        ibo.buffer();

        //==============================================================       
        // Now we tell OpenGL that we will use POSITION_INDEX and COLOR_INDEX
        // to communicate respectively the vertex positions and vertex colors
        // to our shaders.
        {
            // First we enable the indices. This will affect the vertex
            // array object from above.
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(POSITION_INDEX);
            Util.checkGLError();


            // Then we tell OpenGL how it should read the GL_ARRAY_BUFFER
            // (to which we have bound our vertex data, see above).

            // The position data starts at the beginning of the vertex data
            glVertexAttribPointer(POSITION_INDEX, 4, GL_FLOAT, false,
                    2 * VEC4_BYTES, 0);
            Util.checkGLError();

            // The color data starts after the first 4 floats of position data
            glVertexAttribPointer(TEXTURE_INDEX, 2, GL_FLOAT, false,
                    0, VEC4_BYTES);
            Util.checkGLError();
        }

        vbo.bufferData();

        // Just to be VERY clean, we will unbind the vertex attribute object
        // and only bind it when we render. This way we cannot accidentally modify
        // it anymore.
        vao.unbind();

        // Only after the vertex array is disabled, we unbind the buffers
        // to the GL_ARRAY_BUFFER and GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER targets, because
        // otherwise the vertex array object would become invalid again.
        vbo.unbind();

        ibo.unbind();
    }

    void DestroyVBO() {

        glDisableVertexAttribArray(POSITION_INDEX);
        Util.checkGLError();

        glDisableVertexAttribArray(TEXTURE_INDEX);
        Util.checkGLError();

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        Util.checkGLError();

        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        Util.checkGLError();

        glDeleteBuffers(ibo.id);
        Util.checkGLError();

        glDeleteBuffers(vbo.id);
        Util.checkGLError();

        glBindVertexArray(0);
        Util.checkGLError();

        glDeleteVertexArrays(vao.id);
        Util.checkGLError();
    }


    private int[] generateIndices() {
        int c = elements * 3;
        int v[] = { c, c+1, c+2,
                    c, c+3, c+2};
        elements++;
        return v;
    }

    public void render () {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        Util.checkGLError();


        vao.bind();
        glDrawElements(
                GL_TRIANGLES,
                ibo.size,
                GL_UNSIGNED_INT,
                0);
        Util.checkGLError();

        vao.unbind();
    }

}
```

My basic Rectangle class

```
public class BRectangle  {
    final int amountOfVertices = 8;
    final int vertexSize = 3;
    final int textureSize = 2;

    public FloatBuffer vertexData;

    Texture texture;

    public BRectangle(float x, float y ) {
        float[] VerticesArray = new float[]{
                -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                -0.1f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
                -0.1f, 0.4f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                -0.5f, 0.4f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
            };
        vertexData = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(24);
        vertexData.put(VerticesArray);



        try {
            texture = Textures.loadTexture("data/floor.jpg");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture.getTextureID());

    }

}
```

The test with main[]

```
public class ShaderTest {

    ShaderRenderer sr;

    FpsCounter c;

    public ShaderTest() {
    }

    public void create() throws LWJGLException, Exception {

        new SimpleDisplay(800, 600, "test", false, false);
        glOrtho(0, 800, 0, 600, 1, -1);
        //Keyboard
        Keyboard.create();

        c = new FpsCounter();

        Textures.setUpTextureLoader();

        //Mouse
        Mouse.setGrabbed(false);
        Mouse.create();

        sr = new ShaderRenderer();
        //OpenGL
        initGL();


    }


    public void destroy() {
        Mouse.destroy();
        Keyboard.destroy();
        Display.destroy();
    }

    public void initGL() throws IOException {



        ShaderUtilities.compileShader("shaders/screen.vert", "shaders/screen.frag", ShaderRenderer.POSITION_INDEX, ShaderRenderer.TEXTURE_INDEX);
        sr.add(new BRectangle(0f, 0f));
    }

    public void processKeyboard() {
    }

    public void processMouse() {
    }

    public void render() throws LWJGLException {
        sr.render();
    }


    public void run() throws LWJGLException {
        while (!Display.isCloseRequested() && !Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_ESCAPE)) {
            if (Display.isVisible()) {
                processKeyboard();
                processMouse();
                update();
                render();
            } else {
                if (Display.isDirty()) {
                    render();
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                }
            }

            Display.update();
            //Display.sync(60);
        }
    }

    public void update() {
        c.updateFPS();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ShaderTest main = null;
        try {
            main = new ShaderTest();
            main.create();
            main.run();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (main != null) {
                main.destroy();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the openglinit

```
public static void initGLSlim() {
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);

    glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);  

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, 800, 600, 0, 1, -1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

}
```

vertex shader

```
#version 140

in vec4 in_Position;
in vec2 in_Texture;
out vec2 out_Texture;

void main(void)
{
   gl_Position = vec4(in_Position.x *0.75 ,in_Position.y, in_Position.z, in_Position.w);
   out_Texture = in_Texture;
}
```

fragment shader

```
#version 140

in vec2 out_Texture;
uniform sampler2D mytexture;
out vec4 fragColor;

void main(void)
{
   fragColor = texture2D(mytexture, out_Texture);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your stride parameters are not correct.

Here's what you have:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(POSITION_INDEX, 4, GL_FLOAT, false, 2 * VEC4_BYTES, 0); 
glVertexAttribPointer(TEXTURE_INDEX, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, VEC4_BYTES);
```

You're telling the position index that it has 8 float stride, which is not correct. As far as I can tell you're uploading 4 vertices, with 6 floats per vertex (4x position + 2x texture). That means your POSITION stride should be `6 * FLOAT_NUM_BYTES`.

Your texture stride should be the same, as it's packed into the same array. Here you're telling it that the texcoords are tightly packed, but in reality theres only one pair of texcoords per 6 floats. So again you need `6 * FLOAT_NUM_BYTES` here.

---

> And can I reuse my IBO, so I don't have to add the additional indices?

Yes, you can use an IBO to draw as many objects as you want, provided that they all want the same indices.

---

Other less serious comments:

- You don't need to clearColor to zero in initialization, it's zero by
  default.
- You don't need to disable depth_test/lighting in
  initialization, they are off by default.
- Don't call glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D) when you're using shaders. This
  switch only enables texturing for the fixed pipeline, and it has no effect on shader programs. This will generate an error if you ever move to a core profile, so just get rid of it.

Comment: I changed the stride, but there is still nothing displayed (my normal gl_quad test displays the texture). Also, HOW can I reuse the IBO? if i just use 0-3 and set it, the next quads weren't drawn.

Comment: @Frotty I'm not sure why it's not displaying, though there are some critical sections missing from your code. Do you set the "mytexture" uniform value anywhere? Can you show the code where you build the texture (glTexImage2d)? It would probably be best if you just posted everything in it's entirety so there's nothing else missing.

Comment: No I don't set it, probably. I copied it from a 3d texturing tutorial since i didn't find anything in 2d. I pushed everything into a repository https://github.com/Frotty/Buttermilk2D . But i also contains very old code. Thanks for taking your time!

Comment: Hmm, thats a bit more code than I expected. My other two things to check are: make sure you set the texture uniform value to zero (if you're using sampler zero) with glUniform1i, and also make sure that your texture is not using mipmaps ([read here](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Common_Mistakes#Creating_a_Texture))

Comment: I thought I don't have to use that because I'm using the lwjgl Texture ? It worked with the glQuad. Also as I said, much code is unneeded, as the ShaderTest only uses the files I put in the post and the VBO, IBo, etc. classes. Anyways thanks, I will try looking into that link..

Comment: Can you please give me an exmple code on how to setUp the texture properly?

Comment: I'm sure there have to be dozens of tutorials out there that explain how to do texturing with shaders, I suggest you look harder if you say you haven't been able to find anything. If you have any specific questions I can try to answer them, but I'm not going to write code for you. Good luck!

Comment: All the tuts I found don't use lwjgl and perform some actions that interfere with my vbo useage. okay, seems like I found something usful, thanks anyways.

Comment: Okay, the problem I got now, is how to make quads with different textures, using only 1 interleaved VBO and 1 drawElements call.